# Generating n-random float values between -x and y summed up to a predefined value

Tags: python, numpy, random, distribution

I would like to generate n random float values which should be constrainted with a lower and upper bounds, which the total should be also 0 or a predefined value.

For example, I want to generate 4 float values between -10.0 and 2.0, total=0, then following values would work:

```
[-1.0, -1.5, 1.75, 1.75]
```

or 5 floats between -10.0 and 1.0, and total=1.0 then:

```
[0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

is there any generic way or a good distribution method via numpy or a custom function via vanilla Python? If because of the constraints these numbers cannot be summed up to the predefined value than the function could give an error, like:

3 floats between -2.0 and -1.0, total=1.0:

```
raise ValueError
```

Comment: You say float but show numbers without decimal part. Do you want integers?

Comment: @mozway what do you mean? the first example with 4 values are all float values, you could also change `[-1.0, -2.0, 2.0, 1.0]` to `[-1.5, -1.0, 2.0, 0.5]`. It was just an example and writing integer-like floats were easier.

Comment: What you want sounds similar to a Dirichlet distribution https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html, but unfortunately, given your potentially non-symmetric range constraints, I don't think its simple to just scale/offset the output of Dirichlet to match your needs.

Comment: @MattPitkin thank you for this! you are right, unsymmetric ranges makes it hard. With symmetric range it works though!

Comment: For your example of “4 float values between -10.0 and 2.0, total=0”, the range is infeasible. The largest possible positive contribution is three 2.0’s, so the smallest possible value for the range would be -6.0. You could never get a value below -6 and still hit your target sum.

Comment: Similarly, for your second example -3 is a lower bound, not -10.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of algorithm.

```py
import random

def foo(min_: int, max_: int, count: int, target: float) -> list[float]:
    # make sure the target is reachable
    if target < min_ * count or target > max_ * count:
        raise ValueError(f"Target value '{target}' is not valid for allowed range '{min_}' - '{max_}'")

    numbers = []
    
    # execute the next steps `count` times
    for i in range(count):
        # generate a random float number with the allowed range
        number = random.uniform(min_, max_)
        
        current_sum = sum(numbers) + number
        delta = target - current_sum
        current_delta = target - sum(numbers)
        renamining_tries = count - i - 1
        missing = 0
        
        # the last number is what's remaining
        if renamining_tries == 0:
            number = current_delta
        
        # insure that the target is still reachable
        elif delta > renamining_tries * max_:
            min_to_add = delta - renamining_tries * max_
            missing = random.uniform(min_to_add, max_ - number)
            
        elif delta < renamining_tries * min_:
            min_to_remove = renamining_tries * min_ - delta
            missing = -random.uniform(min_to_remove, number - min_)
            
        # correct the number if it needs to be
        number += missing
        numbers.append(number)
        
    return numbers
    
numbers = foo(min_=-10, max_=2, count=4, target=0)
print(sum(numbers), numbers)
```

Basically, I generate random float numbers and make sure that the target is still reachable within the number range. If not, I add to the current number what would be missing to make it reachable. The last number is what's remaining. Because of the check, this would never be outside the allowed range.

Comment: that would work, but if I run this algorithm 1000 times with same parameters, won't be a pattern of always big floats in the first indexes of the list and small floats in the last indexes,? What I was looking for was more like a dice rolling distribution with floats and the bounds could be negative-positive reals. So a flat distribution of all reals between the bounds is expected.

Comment: I'll try to update my answer to fix those issues :)

Comment: @oakca i fixed the bugs. About the flat distributon, it really depends on the constraints. Let's say you want 4 numbers between -10 et 2 to add up to 2, you'll never get un number less than -4 because 3 * 2 + -4 = 2

Comment: maybe that part is hard to solve, I would also accept if you could fix the bounds to -10 and 10 and the total could be some value between -5 and 5. Maybe that way it is easier to solve.

Comment: Wdym by fixing the bounds ? There are parameters you can change as you want when calling the function

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np

n_numbers = 4
total = 10
upper = 100
lower = -100

parts = np.random.rand(n_numbers - 1) * (upper - lower) + lower
parts.sort()
out = np.append(parts[0], np.diff(parts, append=total))
if any(out > upper) or any(out < lower):
    raise ValueError("Oops, something went wrong")
print(out.sum())
```

Let me know if this works for you. I know it is not ideal, but it works most of the times... Is a really interesting task!

The problem with my code is that the last value added to `out` could be higher or lower than defined boundaries.

Comment: >`The problem with my code is that the last value added to out could be higher or lower than defined boundaries.` this is sadly not acceptable plus same problem with the answer below

Comment: No, it does not have the same problem as the answer below. The creation of "my" values are taken independently from the other created values. To be honest I think it is your best bet. If you force to get a solution you will always end up making one or more values dependent from the others. That will result in "false", not entirely random values.